# Twitter OAuth 1.0 "215 Bad Authentication Data" error when requesting token

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, azure-data-factory

My use case is 3-legged auth for my current business to get some impression data from Twitter.  This stuff was a breeze on LinkedIn but I'm falling at the first hurdle with Twitter, having followed docs & videos I'm still running into a "Bad Authentication Data" error when getting an access token.

I've snipped the callback, consumer key and token, but the consumer key is the API key from my Twitter app and the token is the Access Token from the same.  Below is the json. none, signature and timestamp I got auto generated by postman.  Any pointers?

```
{
"name": "get_access_token",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Web1",
            "type": "WebActivity",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "url": "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "OAuth": "oauth_nonce=\"wErUbiAbmCi\", oauth_callback=\"https%3A%2F%2F<snipped>\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1613748394\", oauth_consumer_key=\"<snipped>", oauth_signature=\"hMnZtN5hT5KHRcyrxz8xis33C1c=\", oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_token = \"<snipped>\""
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth headers need to be sorted alphabetically. The documentation is [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature).